# Enable Tab Stop for TextBox in a UserControl exists in StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a user control that consists of a CheckBox and a TextBox. I create instances of this user control dynamically at runtime according to properties of my object and add them into a StackPanel.

I would like to enable Tab navigation between these TextBoxes. Setting IsTabStop="True" for the TextBox in the user control did not worked. I have also set KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Contained" for TextBox but not succeeded.

Comment: have you tried creating a new control based off the old control, then replacing the control with this new one + tab stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

Set KeyBoardNavigation property of the **container not the TextBox**. I do this in code behind because I create my StackPanel instances dynamically.

```
MyStackPanel.IsTabStop = true;    
MyStackPanel.SetValue(KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigationProperty, KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle);
```

Also make sure **TextBox** has IsTabStop property set True:

```
KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True"
```